# Unable to add views to a scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I have a method that takes a viewController and an identifier and returns a viewController. It looks like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)createStepVC:(UIViewController *)viewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    [_scrollView addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    return viewController;
}
```

In viewDidLoad I call it like this:

```
_step1VC = (TNSettingsViewController *)[self createStepVC:_step1VC identifier:@"TNSettingsViewController"];
```

`_step1VC` which is of type `TNSettingsViewController` inherits from UIViewController.

When I try and run it - this happens:

[image]

The scrollView is an `IBOutlet` which is connected. All the storyboard ID's are correct. I have no idea as to why this is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it crash at this line or have you placed a breakpoint manually? If it does, what message is logged to the console?

Comment: @RinatKhanov it crashes there. I have only added an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Show us the backtrace.

Comment: Iterate over the breakpoint a couple times, it should print an error message to the console. Update your question with an error message.

Comment: @RinatKhanov aah, when I did that - I got: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TNSettingsViewController 0x109223460> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key backgroundImage.'
*** First throw call stack:` Now I should be able to figure it out. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, most likely somewhere in your Storyboard you have a view that points to `backgroundImage` outlet which is no longer presented in `TNSettingsViewController`.

Comment: I solved it, but you deserve the "correct answer" - Iterating over the breakpoint gave me a real error I could work with :)